# Arabic date displaying incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arabic, date-format, datetimeformatinfo

I'm using the following code to display an arabic date:

```
Dim dtFormat As DateTimeFormatInfo = New CultureInfo("ar-sa", False).DateTimeFormat
dtFormat.Calendar = New HijriCalendar()

Dim hijriDate As String = Now.ToString("d MMMM yyyy", dtFormat)
```

Today this is displaying as `16 ربيع الثاني 1432`. However, according to a user, the arabic text should be in the middle with the year 1432 at the end.

However, when you highlight the text, it highlights back to front.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with "right to left" Arabic text when it gets mixed in with numbers. How are you displaying it? If you are using a windows control make sure that the `RightToLeft` property is set to `true`. If it's web; use css style `direction:rtl;`

Comment: This is a date in the header of a website. I applied "direction:rtl" to the <p> tag which the date is in, however I don't want all of the text to change as its only one bit which is arabic. I put a span with "direction:rtl" around the date, but this didn't change anything. Then I found out I can do "<span dir='rtl'>" so I tried this and now the date displays with the year on the left, arabic in the middle, and 16 on the right. The user stated the year should be on the right, with the arabic in the middle. Have I done something wrong? Cheers for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using `Dim hijriDate As String = Now.ToString("yyyy MMMM d", dtFormat)`?